# How do I style an active route that has query params?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

`.router-link-exact-active` class is not added to the active route when navigating to that route via `this.$router.push(...)`.

For example:

```
// ...
this.$router.push('/?foo=bar');
```

Will not result in `<router-link :to="'/'">Home</router-link>` being assigned the `.router-link-exact-active` class.

1. Is this a bug, or an intended behaviour?
2. How should the active link be styled in this case?

**P.S**

This is a fiddle illustrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/alexlomm/dumeejyy/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should use `params` or `query` separately and use `query` or `params` value as template data, As in below example

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/', query: url_query }">home</router-link>
```

[Check in docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.7.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Home = {template: ''}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home},
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  template: `
    <div id="app">
      <p>Current path: {{ $route.fullPath }}</p>
      <ul>
        <li><router-link :to="{ path: '/', query: url_query }">home</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  data:{
   url_query:{}
  },
  mounted() {
   this.url_query = { foo: 'bar' };
  }
}).$mount('#app')

</script>
```

[In your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/dumeejyy/11/)

Comment: Already tried that to no avail. Those two approaches are basically the same

Comment: The point is, that it works if you navigate with `router-link`, however it does not work when you navigate by `this.$router.push`.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia : yes because compilation of template is done before, So As I suggest is good way to make it work. Or you decide to put `router-link` after `this.$router.push`. In your case `router-link` never change after `this.$router.push`... did I confuse you or clear your confusion ?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean you can't update url here `<router-link :to="'/'">Home</router-link>` until it is not bind. as I did in example.